# Making text bigger and smaller

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make an application on Android Studio. I have 2 buttons. a plus and a minus. I need to know how to make the text smaller and bigger everytime I click on one of these buttons.

This is my MainActivity.java:

```
    Button Min = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Min);
    Min.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DeText);
            t.setTextSize(-5);
        }
    });
```

This is my .xml:

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Plus"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="50dp"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Min"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:text="-"
        android:textSize="50dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/DeText"
        android:text="Text"/>
```

I also have made a screenshot of the page I'm working on. Hopefully this gives some more information about my end product:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `sp` instead of `dp` for text sizes. From **[documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextSize%28int,%20float%29)**, you can use `setTextSize` method and it includes two arguments.

> void setTextSize (int unit, 
>                   float size)

So, you can specify the text size after button click as:

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DeText);
        text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,text.getTextSize()-1);
    }
});
```

Comment: You must include this code inside `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 1):

You simply set the text size by getting the current size and adding/subtracting the value you want.

```
Button minButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Min);
    minButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            TextView t = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.DeText);
            t.setTextSize(COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, t.getTextSize() - 5f);
        }
    });
```

It would be better to check if the current text size is not too small before reducing the size.

Comment: And what about making it smaller?

Comment: Try the updated answer with '- 5f' as well as '+ 5f'.